# Define a class dynamically?

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way to dynamically and conditionally create a class definition in PHP, i.e.

```
if (condition matches)
  include file containing class definition
else
  class myclass extends ancestor_class { .................... }
```

without `eval()`?

My background is the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425057/having-the-option-of-customized-classes-but-a-unified-class-name). I am looking for the best way to build a untouchable core library, with user-defined empty classes extending the core library if necessary.

I want to create the final class definition "on the fly" if there is no user-defined empty class for a certain ancestor class.

Including another include file (containing the empty class definition) is out of the question, as there will be quite a number of classes.

> **Update:** This seems to be possible in a normal condition block - didn't think of that. However, according to [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2004/03/31/conditional-class-declaration-bad-practice/), it also seems to be regarded as bad practice and may be removed in the future. Hmm. Creative ideas welcome.

Comment: If you don't want your users to create the files with empty definitions, could you not create them dynamically, when needed, and include them after ? *(That's probably what I would do -- not sure if it's a suitable solution for you, though...)*

Comment: @Pascal Good idea basically, but it's going to be a packaged application, and I may not have the rights to write files in the library path.

Comment: Writing in the library path would probably not be safe either ; but what about writing those to some "cache" directory *(your application will probably have one writable directory, for caching, logging, ...)*, and use that directory as a portion of the `include_path` *(with some require/autoloading magic, maybe ?)* for your application ?

Comment: @Pascal good point! Doesn't feel right to me to write code into the cache directory but it may indeed be the only solid choice without resorting to `eval()`. Maybe, I'm beginning to think, this is one of those very few cases where `eval()` is justified, especially as the code is just this: `class myclass extends myclass_ancestor {}` I think I'll play around with both, thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but have a look at Zend_CodeGenerator: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.codegenerator.html

Comment: I would rather create files containing code than use eval : using files means easier to debug *(just in case, even for empty classes)*, and it also means that opcode caching *(with APC, or tools like that)* is possible -- Trying conditionnal class declaration, it seems to be working ; I'm surprised, I thought it was only possible for functions, and not classes ^^

Comment: @Gordon the link is very good to know, thank you! ZF really has something for everything.... @Pascal you're right. Eval() is horribly kludgy. I think I will resort to keeping a directory with empty final classes somewhere in the core, and tweaking the autoloader so it looks there if it doesn't find anything in the user library. More manual work (because you have to maintain the final class files) but the simplest way to go. Thanks for the input! Would you like to answer so I can close the question?

Comment: OK for posting an answer -- I'll try to summarize our comments :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be feasible in your scenario to return an instance of the base class or a default-extending class for that purpose? Exactly why do you need the empty classes that extend a base class? Because of a naming schema (which can probably be avoided) or because you need a non-abstract class to instantiate an object?

Comment: @VolkerK I am employing the autoloader only to load the proper file(s), but not to instantiate the class, so I need a fixed class name (e.g. `classname_final` or just `classname`). To achieve that, I need to follow the pattern `classname_ancestor` in core file, `classname` in app file. I don't see any other way to do this except to have a helper function choose the right class name depending on whether there is an extended class, which I wouldn't feel comfortable with. Any alternative ideas how to do this are of course very welcome.

Comment: Ah ok, you're already in the autoloader. Then it's certainly too late for the kind of decision I suggested. But somewhere the decision to load/instantiate/use class\_arbitrary must have been made and it's probably not hardcoded (would surprise me a lot). Do you have influence (and the time to change and test it) on that part of the code? Or can you "only" react on a request for a specific class, a request you can't change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*See the comments under the question for more information -- I'll try to summarize, as it might be useful to other :-)*

First of all, I suppose the goal is not having users create almost empty files by themselves -- I remember another question, I think it was from you, where that popped up.

If so, why not just create those almost empty files dynamically ?

I mean, some idea like that :

```
if (condition matches) {
    include file containing class definition
} else {
    create another file containg the alternate class definition
    include that other file
}
```

As @Gordon said in a comment, a possibility, to makes things a bit easier, would be to use [`Zend_CodeGenerator`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.codegenerator.html), to help with that task of code-generation.

As pointed out : the users will not likely have write-access on the `library` directory, but nothing prevents you from creating those files into another "*cache*" directory -- afterall, it's likely that your application has write-access to at least one directory :

- For cache ^^
- Or, at least, for logs

A solution would be to use `eval`:

- build a string containing the class' definition
- `eval`uate it

But I would really not do that, for at least two reasons :

- Debugging will probably be harder -- even for an almost empty file/string
- Using a file means there is a possibility for opcode caching *(APC, or similar tools)*
- And, as a third, thinking about it : having a file means your IDE can parse it -- might help with code-completion, type-hinting, ...

Seeing your update, I tried conditional declaration :

```
if (false) {
    class A {
        public $a = 10;
    }
} else {
    class A {
        public $a = 20;
    }
}

$a = new A();
var_dump($a);
```

Changing the condition from false to true and vice-versa, I get two alternate output :

```
object(A)[1]
  public 'a' => int 20

object(A)[1]
  public 'a' => int 10
```

So... well, seems to be working!

*(I'm surprised, I thought it was only possible for functions!)*

But, still, I don't really like that idea... Not sure how it behaves in IDEs -- and I like having one class per file...

*(Yeah, personnal opinion)*

Comment: +1 Very good points as always, thanks for testing and making me aware of the IDE implications.

Comment: You're welcome ; and thanks :-) ;;; I didn't think about those, when commenting -- but thought about IDE when writing, so... *(IDE and opcode cache are two reasons which make me hate `create_function` -- and eval's a bit like that ^^ )*

Comment: Unfortunately your example does not work when `class A` is used after the `extends` command. I don't understand why, but that's the fact in PHP 7.x